# Thread synchronization to ensure threads don't overlap

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost

I have two threads, of which one of them runs continuously with a periodicity of 1 second independently. The second thread sends some requests, parallel to the first one, and during one particular request of the second thread, the difference between the requests of first thread and the second thread should be at least 50 milliseconds.  How can i make sure that the request from first thread does not overlap with that particular request of second thread?

I thought of getting the time-stamp of first thread in the second thread and make the first one sleep for 50ms before it starts sending the request again. Is the solution feasible? is it possible in C++?? If not it would be helpful if you suggest a solution. I am a newbie in threading, so please don't mind if it is kind of silly question.

EDIT:
Can someone please provide me an example on how to do this using Boost Library. Also the two threads, first thread and second thread are written in two different dll's.

Comment: I think your timestamp approach would work.  Another solution would be to use a dedicated spooler thread that serializes all requests for the other threads.  I'm not sure what answer you're exactly after.

Comment: Could you possibly explain what is your goal? It is strange thing  you try to do here.

Comment: +1 @5gon12eder's, to add to that, I'd have a function that queues your requests which is locked with a mutex (therefore queuing your request is a blocking call that is guaranteed to be thread-safe because of the mutex) and in the background have a thread that works off sending those requests in the queue. This assumes that "sending a request" takes time and you don't want it to be a blocking call. Also, you'll have to have some error handling if you start to overfill your queue (takes longer to send requests then it takes to queue more). You can ensure you have your time gap in that thread.

Comment: Also, a lot of the time if you are checking clocks in different threads you have to be very careful because depending on the implementation of the clock they might not correlate to each other.

Comment: For me it sounds like an XY problem. If you have to synchronize with sleep and sending requests breaks your algorithms your design seems to be broken. Instead of searching the "correct" implementation of a wrong design I would step back to make a robust design.

Answer (score 0):

[Edit:
as Mateusz Grzejek stated in the comments, [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable) is actually better suited for this use (<s>i'm still unsure of why this solution is considered invalid, but even if it wasn't,</s> use condition_variable, not compare-and-swap)
]

[Edit: the following (and my original) solution doesn't actually work because when you retrieve the current time, you don't have any guarantee concerning its accurracy (especially for high precision), hence there is no guarantee that you can't actually get the same timestamp after 100ms, or conversely even make a jump of 500ms in 100ms.
In general, as Mateusz Grzejek stated, you should not rely on directly retrieving the timestamp for synchronization, but instead use dedicated function which will lock/unlock after a given amount of time (fortunately `std::condition_variable` seems to allow that, as Mateusz Grzejek stated)
]

<s>It is feasible, you can have an atomic timestamp (in miliseconds) variable which will be the next time when a thread will be able to send the next request, then when a thread wants to send a request, it follows these steps:</s>

- first load the value of that timestamp in a local variable
- check whether that value is greater than the current timestamp (if so, sleep for the difference, then start from scratch)
- [compare-and-swap](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compare-and-swap) (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic_compare_exchange) the timestamp and your local variable (if they are equal, set it to the current time in milliseconds + 50)
- if the compare-and-swap succeeded, send the request, otherwise, sleep for 50ms and start from scratch

Edit: an "atomic" operation means that no other thread can interrupt that operation, you can't divide it, hence "atomic" (each of these steps may be cut in interrupted by the other thread then pursued later except for the atomic compare-and-swap, this is important)

Comment: If you downvote, please explain why (not that i care whether i have negative ratings, but i'd like to be able to correct myself when you suggest i'm mistaken)

Comment: I don't know why this answer was down-voted but a problem I see is that you must know in advance how long it will take you to issue your request and add that time to the 50 ms increment you add to the current time.  This might be difficult to do in practice.

Comment: This will not work: `if they are equal, set it to the current time in milliseconds`. Clocks have certain resolution, so there is possibility, that it will *miss* that point in time. Also, your idea is just a home-made, invalid replacement for [`std::condition_variable`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable), which should be used in this case. These two threads should be probably controlled by an external mechanism, that will properly initialize their waiting intervals and then let them `wait_for` 50 ms.

Comment: @5gon12eder I don't know either, but that's not what has been asked so i assume it's a different problem (this is only supposed to ensure that the request that no request has been sent less than 50ms after the last one)

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek I think he means the local variable he is referring to in the first bullet point.  This seems valid to me.

Comment: The problem is that you only ensure no request is sent within 50ms after another thread *got permission* to send a request.  There can (and will) be a delay between the “get permission” and “send request” event that you're not accounting for.

Comment: @Mateusz Grzejek you're right, std::condition_variable is better (i'll edit to to indicate the comment). As for whether my solution invalid, it only is if the cores don't see the "same time" (which might be possible, i'm not sure, and didn't think of that) otherwise i don't really see why precision is relevant here, could you explain further?

Comment: @5gon12eder Declare two conditional variables and let threads signal themselves. First thread: send - signal - wait(50) - send... Second thread: wait(50) - send - signal - wait(50)... First threads waits on `cv_1`, that is signalled by second thread and vice versa. Done. Ideally, these signaling would be done by controller thread, that receives requests (which is automatically scalable (with some adjustments) for a larger number of threads).

Comment: @Mateusz Grzejek ah i think i got your point, you're telling that it is possible that when getting the current time, i actually get a past time (let's say 200ms ago), is that it?

Comment: @Caninonos Topic of getting timestamps in multi-threading apps is something, that would take 2 or 3 **quite long** answers to explain. In addition, in multi-core systems (quite common these days), things go absolutely crazy. Don't rely on that - use synchronization primitives provided by the language or compiler/platform-specific things. Their authors know what are they doing.

Comment: @MateuszGrzejek My comment referred to the original answer, not your suggestion of using condition variables.

Comment: @MateusGrzejek Thanks, i updated my answer and i'll be more aware of that if i have to synchronize threads!

Comment: @Caninonos Looks better now. And remember, there are usually hundreds other threads, that are running in your system - they also take time. Inter-thread synchronization is a difficult topic.

Answer (score 0):

The tick rate should be known depending on the environment you're running in. In the case of Window XP or later, the default tick rate is 64 hz, or 15.625 ms, and you can change this with timeBeginPeriod(), to set the rate to 1000hz or 1ms, but in the case of Windows XP, it ends up being 1024hz, with 3 double delays (2/1024hz) every 128 ticks (on the 43rd, 86th, 128th tick) to end up on a 125 ms boundary. You could read the time stamp after sending a request from the first thread, and before sending a request from the second thread, but there's the potential issue of the second thread getting delayed by nearly 1 second and end up sending it's special request within 50ms of the first threads next request.

You could send all requests via a synchronized fifo messaging system (like a single linked list with a separate head pointer, mutex and semaphore for each thread) to a third thread, that retrieves the request and does the actual request send. The messages would include a thread id and special request identifier. The third thread would do a 50 ms delay as needed before sending the request.